# Android push notification when app is close

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the documentation of google to implement push notifications.
When the app is open works fine, but when I close the app does not receive notifications.

Here is the code:
Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="it.bsdsoftware.cnabologna.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<permission
        android:name="it.bsdsoftware.cnabologna.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<application>
    ...
    <service android:name=".notifiche.RegistrationIntentService"
             android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".notifiche.MyGcmListenerService"
             android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".notifiche.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
             android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".notifiche.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
              android:exported="true"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="it.bsdsoftware.cnabologna" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

RegistrationIntentService.java

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.notifiche_push_sender_id), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        }
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        OperazioneInvioToken op = new OperazioneInvioToken(token);
        WebServiceTask ws = new WebServiceTask(op, this, false);
        ws.execute();
    }

}
```

MyGcmListenerService.java

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        Bundle notification = data.getBundle("notification");

        String title = "";
        String message = "";

        if(notification!=null){
            title = notification.getString("title");
            message = notification.getString("body");
        }

        NotificationUtility.showNotification(title, message);
        NotificationUtility.setBadge(1);
    }
}
```

MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyGcmListenerService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

When the app is open onMessageReceived of GcmListenerService class is called but when the app is closed is not called.

What did I do wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by updating the play service from com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 to com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0